# android - error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): connection reset

Tags: android, windows, adb, wsl-2

I'm on a Windows 10 environment with WSL2 Ubuntu running, and after some difficulty port forwarding my adb on Windows in order for it to communicate with my WSL2 environment, I was able to run my apps via my WSL's adb installation.

These are the steps I followed in order for my WSL2's adb to see my devices on Windows: https://gist.github.com/monicalabbao/b303b260f0acba16735be2483f5210c5

The adb worked fine for both my WSL2 runtime and my Windows a few days until I opened my Android Studio on Windows to work on a native Android app, and now my Android Studio is no longer able to start its ADB:

```
6:14 PM error: protocol fault (couldn't read status): connection reset

6:14 PM 'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

My adb's Inbound Rules in the Windows Firewall are both Public and Private, and they are allowed to receive traffic from both local and remote IP addresses, in any scope.

I also have a custom rule that allows my WSL2 environment to communicate to my Windows environment within the scope of my home network's subnet.

Here's what I did to try fixing the problem:

1. Restart adb.exe - adb.exe isn't found in my Task Manager in the first place.
2. Restart Android Studio - Same problem
3. Restart computer - the problem did not go away
4. Manually restarting my ADB by `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` on my PowerShell, still happens.
5. Run Android Studio as administrator
6. `adb kill-server` and `adb -a -P 5037 nodaemon server` on my PowerShell.
7. Permit Android Studio to operate through my Windows Firewall on public networks (Inbound Rules)
8. Cold booted an emulator. - The protocol fault simply repeated itself.
9. Redownloaded my `\platform-tools` for my Android SDK

Here's my active ports in my Android studio: (`netstat -ab`)

```js
[studio64.exe] TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 59952 [MY-PC]: 59951 ESTABLISHED
[studio64.exe] TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 59953 [MY-PC]: 59954 ESTABLISHED
[studio64.exe] TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 59954 [MY-PC]: 59953 ESTABLISHED
[studio64.exe] TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 59955 [MY-PC]: 59956 ESTABLISHED
[studio64.exe] TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 59956 [MY-PC]: 59955 ESTABLISHED
[studio64.exe] TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 60511 [MY-PC]: 60512 TIME_WAIT
  TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 60518 [MY-PC]: 60519 TIME_WAIT
  TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 60522 [MY-PC]: 60523 TIME_WAIT
  TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 60535 [MY-PC]S: 60536 ESTABLISHED
[studio64.exe] TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 60536 [MY-PC]: 60535 ESTABLISHED
[studio64.exe] TCP 127.0 .0 .1: 63342 [MY-PC]: 0 LISTENING
[studio64.exe] TCP 172.31 .192 .1: 139 [MY-PC]: 0 LISTENING
```

I also noticed that OriginWebHelperService and svchost are using ports 5554 and 5037 for some reason -- ports that I associate with my ADB and my emulator:

```html
[OriginWebHelperService.exe] TCP 127.0.0.1:5037 [MY-PC]:0 LISTENING
  iphlpsvc
[svchost.exe] TCP 127.0.0.1:5554 [MY-PC]:0 LISTENING
```

That above might be a lead to what's going on, but I am not sure.

It is clear that my ADB's connection is reset, but not by a peer.

Short of resetting my PC, what could I have missed or have done to make my ADB act out this way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply did a System Restore to a time before I started port forwarding to TCP 5554, and started adding new firewall rules. ADB daemon started at TCP port 5037 and that was it.

```
8:18 AM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

8:18 AM * daemon started successfully
```